# Default value SqlCommand.Parameters.Add C# Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a program that connect to a database, use a stored procedure to insert a line in a table, and close the connection. Everything works ok instead of the line below.

VisualStudio underline in red the last line :

```
string value = textBox_value.Text;

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) ? DBNull.Value : value));
```

Error message :

> There is no explicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'

`String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)` returns **true** if the value is empty, else returns **false**.

I found the solution by writting this enourmous line of code :

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) 
{
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", DBNull.Value));
}
else 
{
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", CT_Intitule));
}
```

But is that normal we can't perform a one-line condition ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to *Rahul Singh*, that pointed the MSDN documentation in which the function is described as expecting 2 same type, I resolved my issue doing this :

```
command.Parameters.Add
(
    ( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) ) ? 
        new SqlParameter("@value", CT_Intitule) 
        : 
        new SqlParameter("@value", DBNull.Value)
);
```

Comment: It sounds that's happening because of `?:` operator since it's expressions have to convert to each other an implicit way at least..

Comment: Yep, I think I am understanding what is happening. Actually, `? :` condition expect the two parameters to be the same type. I didn't get this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix you code casting the DBNull.Value to object

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", 
                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) 
                     ? (object)DBNull.Value
                     : CT_Intitule);
```

But I wish to discourage the usage of the overload that pass directly the value.
It is always better and more error safe to always specify the parameter type

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@value", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value =
                     string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) 
                     ? (object)DBNull.Value
                     : CT_Intitule;
```

You could read more about the effects of the C# code on database performances here

[How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):-

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

`Conditional Operator` expects both types to be same, for example you cannot do:-

```
string test = 1 == 1 ? "True" : 5;
```

It will throw the same error because there is no implicit conversion possible between a `string` ("True") and `int` (5).

Comment: Yes this is exact. I am updating my question with the solution I found, it was not that hard, thanks for pointing !